piano newbie confused about how this strange (maybe) chord works
i recently started trying to learn the piano with some mediocre background knowledge of notes and their usage, however when tryng to copy a sheet of music into a midi maker, i came across a strange note that appears to be a chord but the two ntoe have different values. I was just wondering if this type of note/chord has a specific term for it, or if it was an error wth the sheet music 
notice the note on top is a (dotted eighth note) and they dont share stems even though they are on the same beat (maybe).

Please upload a version of the picture that doesn't obscure relevant information. The circles you've made really get in the way of reading the notes.

This question is similar to: Rest above a note in a piano piece. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

And please include clef and key signatures

@nuggethead - in general, yes. For this question, the pitches of the notes don't matter so much as their rhythmic values.

This is pretty common in music notation, especially in piano scores and wherever there is polyphony. What actually happens is that the right hand plays two distinct voices. That's why they are notated and grouped with different stems and beams.
More specifically, when you play the C-A bichord on the first movement of the measure, you should keep the C down even when you play the G of the upper voice, since the C of the lower voice lasts a quarter. Likewise, in the second half of the measure, the B of the lower voice, being a dotted crotchet, will have to remain lowered while you play the notes of the upper voice G-F-E.
In this case, the reason why the notes were not written as part of the same chord is also dictated by typography: in fact, immoderate use of value ligatures would have been employed, which would have compromised the immediate readability of the passage.
